# Adding Params to Paging Links (.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Right now, in my page links on the view file, I have:

```
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, numberPerPage = ViewBag.numberPerPage, submit = ViewBag.submit }))
```

However, due to filters when a person searches the data, the params can change such that the url looks like:

```
http://localhost:000/Search?Category=Cats&Category=Dogs&SearchString=brown&numberPerPage=10&submit=adoptable
```

How can I add these on to the view page?  A user may not use the filters.  I am grabbing them via ViewBag, so they are there in the html like:

```
cats,dogs
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show action method and view?

Comment: I figured it out.  I will add the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out how to do what I need to.  Reading up, special urls can only be appended as a string to `Url.Action`.  So what I did was:

```
public ActionResult Index(string SearchString, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string numberPerPage, int? page, string[] Category)
{

    ..........

    ViewBag.CategoryPager = "";
    foreach (var singleCategory in Category)
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryPager += "&Category=" + Category.Replace(" ", "%20");
    }

    .........

   return View(searchResults.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

And in the view:

```
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, numberPerPage = ViewBag.numberPerPage }) + ViewBag.CategoryPager)
```